# PHP Internals: Where are Arrays Created

Tags: php, php-internals

What code in the [php-src repo](https://github.com/php/php-src) handles a PHP programmer creating an array?

That is -- as a PHP programmer I might do something like this

```
$foo = array();
$foo = [];
```

Behind the scenes, I assume there's some bit of central PHP internals code that's alloc-ing out the `zvalue_value` and `zval` structs.  Where is that code?

Bonus -- if this is a dumb question -- why is it a dumb question? (i.e. what mis-assumption about the PHP Internals handling of an array am I missing?)

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](https://nikic.github.io/2012/03/28/Understanding-PHPs-internal-array-implementation.html)

Zend/zend_hash.c
Zend/zend_hash.h

Have array international code.